# Given an $m$ by $n$ array. The entry is 1 with probability $p$, and 0 otherwise. Find probability of having no rectangles with all vertices being 1.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

For small $m$, it is possible to solve it by hand. But, I find it difficult when $m$ goes more than $4$, especially many double-counting will happen. I tried recurrence relation, but failed. I do not think it is possible to derive a closed expression. If there is no closed expression, is it possible to derive a lower bound? I am free to discuss with any opinions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Google search with keywords group "rectangle free boolean arrays" gives this book : "Recent Progress in the Boolean Domain"
edited by Bernd Steinbach (available as a Google book)

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A255256